# PHP Error - usort(): Returning bool from comparison function is deprecated, return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero

Tags: php

I'm having problems with an Magento extension.

getting this error:
main.ERROR: Deprecated Functionality: **usort**(): Returning bool from comparison function is deprecated, return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero in /public_html/magento244/app/code/Magezon/Builder/Data/Groups.php on line 57 [] []

I think it's not ready for PHP 8.1.7

Where can be the error here:
?

```
public function getGroups()
{
    if ($this->sortableElements == null && $this->groups) {
        $sortableElements = [];
        $groups           = [];
        foreach ($this->groups as $type => $group) {
            if (!isset($group['name'])) continue;
            if (!isset($group['sortOrder'])) $group['sortOrder'] = 0;
            $sortableElements[] = [
                'name'      => $group['name'],
                'type'      => $type,
                'sortOrder' => $group['sortOrder']
            ];
        }
        usort($sortableElements, function($firstLink, $secondLink) {
            return ($firstLink['sortOrder'] > $secondLink['sortOrder']);
        });
        $this->sortableElements = $sortableElements;
    }
    return $this->sortableElements;
}
```

Comment: return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero

Comment: Use `<=>` instead of `>`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op